# .htaccess setting is not working on Google Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, browser, cakephp

I am using CakePHP framework, it redirect everything to the app folder using .htaccess, and then I set up a WordPress blog in /news/ folder outside of CakePHP, so I don't want everything in /news/ to be redirect, so I modify the .htaccess, and here is the final version:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
    RewriteEngine on   
    RewriteBase /   
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]   
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]   
</IfModule>
```

It's working fine in IE and FireFox, I can visit mydomain/news/, but in Google Chrome, it still redirects to CakePHP app folder. How can I fix this?

Update: I found that I can visit /news/somepage, but can't visit the /news/

Comment: clear your cache in chrome maybe?  this sounds weird to me. mod_rewrite happens at the server so i don't know why Chrome would behave differently.

Answer (score 4):

Might want to try clearing your Chrome cache - if you had an old rule that caused a "hard" redirect or delivered a 404/403 status message, it may still be in there.

Answer (score 1):

I can visit  honstars.com/news/ with Chrome.Please check the set of you browser.

Comment: Seconded.  Mac Chrome (latest) it loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this one, but try with a user agent test -  `RewriteCond  %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^BrowserName.*` . Are you sending any additional headers?

Comment: I am not sure about other headers, here is my website: http://honstars.com

the news page:

http://honstars.com/news/